# Using Java's ByteBuffer to read millions of messages

Tags: java, io, nio, bytebuffer

Here's my problem: one big gzipped file; millions of messages.

Each message consists of:

```
***************** *************** ****************** 
* 2-byte LENGTH * * 1-byte TYPE * * N-byte PAYLOAD * , where N = (LENGTH-1).
***************** *************** ******************
```

Depending on the `TYPE`, I need to read a few bytes from an offset in the `PAYLOAD` and choose to accept or reject the message.

I know how to do this sort of thing using java.io.DataInputStream, but this seems like a perfect application of java.nio.ByteBuffer ([see here!](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/io/nio_buffers.shtml)). However, I need some help setting it up.

So, *how do I use ByteBuffer to read messages from my gzipped file?*

**Update**

I guess what I'd like to see is a skeletal implementation of code that could get me on the right track to using ByteBuffer effectively. Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote? I've tried to frame my question the best I can. I'd really like to see some sample code using ByteBuffer; I'm having trouble understanding it from what I've read online :(

Comment: `@GregS:` You wouldn't use ByteBuffer for this?

Comment: I can see using a bytebuffer; the DataInputStream api is kind of a mismatch because you have the byte array in memory and don't need to close a resource.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to not answer your question, but I'm not sure there's any benefit to using ByteBuffer over DataInputStream here. You'll probably want to put your stream through GZIPInputStream to inflate the data.

```
GZIPInputStream gzipInput = new GZIPInputStream(yourInputStream);
DataInputStream dataInput = new DataInputStream(gzipInput);
```

With ByteBuffer you'd probably just be wrapping the bytes read from your input stream, with no advantage.

Comment: Fully agree -- very hard to see any point in trying to use ByteBuffer here

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing everything for your protocol at a low level, why not use a library like Mina or Netty? They can provide you with fairly easy to implement a solution.

Mina http://mina.apache.org/

Netty http://www.jboss.org/netty

As an aside, we use Mina in Red5 and we lots of implementers processing millions and millions of messages.

Comment: Downvoted as this doesn't answer the question that was asked.  Question does not indicate asker is writing a networked message processing application, which is what both of these frameworks are for.  I also don't believe either of them is capable of handling gzipped data, although may be wrong in this.